# What is wrong with this statement below

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

What is wrong with this statment below? I get "; expected" when run it in LinqPad with language setting to "C# Statement".

```
from p in Products where p.UnitPrice > 50 select new {p.ProductID };
```

Now seem like if I assign it to any var; I don't get any error. But what I find confusing is the statement below works fine and give me results back although I don't assign it to any variable. Any ideas?

```
    from p in Products
let spanishOrders = p.OrderDetails.Where ( o=> o.Order.ShipCountry == "Spain")
where spanishOrders.Any()
group new
{
    p.ProductName,
    Orders = spanishOrders.Count(),
    spanishOrders
}
by p.Category.CategoryName
```

**EDIT:** It was my bad actually i couldn't run the second example without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code, please?

Comment: Is the code in an application or are you actually using LINQ Pad (saw the linqpad tag...it can make a difference)?

Comment: What is your language setting in LINQPad?

Comment: updated question with more details

Comment: If you are in "C# Expression" language mode, you have to drop the semi-colon in your first example.  See my post below.

Comment: I get '; expected' if I try to run the second example as a C# statement.

Comment: What version of LINQPad are you using?  4.31 Free version?

Comment: @Alex: Yes it 4.31 free version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LINQ Query expressions are not legal statements in C#. You need to *use* the expression in a valid statement.

For example, you could use the expression as the right-hand side of an assignment statement:

```
var expensiveProductIds = from p in Products
                          where p.UnitPrice > 50 
                          select new { p.ProductID };
```

It does appears to me like you don't really understand what LINQ is all about. What did you *expect* your naked query expression to do?

**EDIT**: Take a look at Alex Moore's answer for how to get this to work in LINQPad.

By the way, here's a way to get the results of the query written to console if you still want to stick with the "C# Statement(s)" mode:

```
var expensiveProductIds = from p in Products
                          where p.UnitPrice > 50 
                          select new { p.ProductID };

expensiveProductIds.Dump();
```

Comment: LINQPAD has a mode, `Expression` that executes statements just as he wrote them (minus the trailing semicolon). I _presume_ that is how s/he expected it to work.

Comment: He/She is trying out the expression in LINQPad, not in C# as a statement.

Comment: LINQPAD has a Lanuage combo, I have choosen "c# statment" from there. Just to be clear, there is another option "C# Expression" but that is NOT what i am using in this case.

Comment: @Marc: LINQPad statement mode, just like the C# compiler, does *not* accept query expressions trying to masquerade as statements (by ending them with a semicolon).

Comment: @Ani:  Yes Its true I am completely new to Linq and struggling to go through the initial hump. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using "**C# Expression**" as the Language in the LinqPad language drop down, you have to drop the semi-colon because it's just an expression:

```
from p in Products where p.UnitPrice > 50 select new {p.ProductID }
```

If you are using "**C# Statement(s)**" as the language, you will have to write it out like regular C# code:

```
var x = (from p in Products where p.UnitPrice > 50 select new {p.ProductID });
```

LINQPad lets you test both ways, because some queries are easier when you get the statements out of the way.

Comment: I added an example in question where I can run it as "C# statment" without assigning it back to a var

Comment: I get '; expected' if I try to run the second example as a C# statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
            var db = new DataContext();
            var product= from p in db.Products 
                          where p.UnitPrice > 50
                          select new{ProductId = p.ProductID };
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that looks weird to me is that in your new anonymous object, you aren't assigning the ProductID to a property, but I guess it's not really required (I just tried it).

```
from p in Products where p.UnitPrice > 50 select new { ProductID = p.ProductID };
```

**EDIT**: Due to the comments, I realize this will not provide anything useful for solving the the OP's problem.

Comment: You dont need to specify a property name if you are assigning a field or property, and you want that name still. Very handy indeed!

Comment: `new { p.ProductID }` and `new { ProductID = p.ProductID }` will produce the same anonymous type.

Comment: @cadrell0: Didn't know that (updated my answer)! I guess I just always like to be explicit with those darned anonymous types :)

Comment: I used to always be explicit, then I got ReSharper and it started scolding me.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the result to a variable.

```
var v = from p in Products where p.UnitPrice > 50 select new {p.ProductID };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not a valid C# statement.

Either assign the value of your expression to a variable:

```
var q = from p in ... ;
```

Or remove the semicolon at the end and change the Language to *C# Expression*

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it to something.

```
var productIds = from p in Products where p.UnitPrice > 50 select new {p.ProductID };
```

Answer (score -2):

you are trying to select after getting it assigned so . so you should use some thing like this

```
from p in Products where p.UnitPrice > 50 select 
                                                new { 
                                                      ProductID = p.ProductID 
                                                    };
```

Comment: That's the same code except you have some new lines.  And a redundant property name in your anonymous type.