# LINQPad query does not return result when using GroupBy and First or FirstOrDefault (semicolon)

Tags: linqpad

In LINQPad 7 a relatively simple `GroupBy` query returns results but when you add `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` - the result is not returned.

*(Processes is the table I am targeting in this example but I don't think that is the cause for the problem.)*

**Results**

```
Processes
    .GroupBy(p => p.CreatedDate)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
    .Select(g => new { CreatedDate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
```

[image]

**No Result**

```
Processes
    .GroupBy(p => p.CreatedDate)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
    .Select(g => new { CreatedDate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .First();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the answer turned out to be simple. **Change to Language: 'C# Expression' and DO NOT include a semicolon when using just a query (expression). This then returned the expected result** This Answer on SO - helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011393/427684

[image]

If you want full valid C# with a semicolon then change to Language 'C# Statement' - store the result in a variable and then use LINQPad extension method `.Dump()`

[image]

Comment: Note that you can also just put `.Dump();` after the `.First()` and not need a variable, but that begs the question why aren't you using C# Expression mode :)